# Is it OK to embed database object?

Tags: php, database, oop, class

I have the following data tables: users, user_pictures, messages, forum. To outline it's structure:

```
forum
users
 user_pictures
 messages
```

since if no users, no user_pictures neither messages. Now I want to this structured logic to be build in my classes. I use a standalone class for each tables to do the actions according to the table. Normally it would look like this:

```
$forum = new Forum();

$users = new User();

$messages = new Message();

$user_pictures = new User_picture();
```

but what if if I create messages and user_pictures in the constructor of users? And it's reference would be there too. Is it OK?

Comment: To me, it LOOKS like you're saying that logically, `user_pictures` and `messages` are both owned by `users`, and that you're asking whether or not it's sound OOP to construct those objects accordingly... is that accurate?

Comment: What is in each of your standalone classes, and can you give examples of how they would be used.  I would say you could just create instances where they are required though...

Answer (score 1):

> but what if if I create messages and user_pictures in the constructor of users?

You should not create *anything* in the ctor. That would be doing work in the ctor and its also mixing creation graph with collaborator graph. If you want to assemble a complex object graph, use a Builder or a Factory pattern. If you need to create something *in* a collaborator, pass an instance of a factory or builder to the collaborator. [But dont do work in a constructor.](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)

As for the remainder of your question: this [can be answered the same as your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900353/is-it-ok-to-make-a-class-object-for-a-database-table). Use a custom DataMapper and/or Repository and/or an ORM. Dont model your classes after your RDBMS structure.

Comment: Not only because of testing. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your logic will depend on what $messages and $user_pictures really is. Are they the messages and pictures for that user only or are they the forums'?

If it's the first case, then $messages and $user_pictures should sub class $user as they are associated with that class. If it's the later, then they should sub class $forum. If they are unrelated, then they should all be their own classes.

If you're gonna sub class $users with $messages and $user_pictures, I would create a method on the user object to access those sub classes. Something like $user->get_messages to get the messages associated with that user, same for user pictures.